# How can I sleep in a windows batch file within a non-interactive session?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that is executed outside of an interactive command prompt.   I want to sleep for 30 seconds between two commands in it?

I've read in some responses to similar questions that you can use `timeout` or `choice`, but these fail in a non-interactive session.

```
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.
```

I've read in other responses to similar questions that you can use `waitfor`, but this will set an error level and I rely on those in the overall script.

I've seen using a ping that will fail `ping -n 1 -w 30000 192.168.not.reachable > NUL` and this appears to work, but that just seems wrong and I can't rely on an single IP being not reachable on all systems I'll deploy to.

Is there another way for me to try?

Thanks.

EDITS:

This answer ([How to sleep in a batch file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file))  definitely has related material, but doesn't address the need for a solution that works outside an interactive shell.   It does mention the only alternative I have now:  `ping`, but as I ask above, I'm looking for alternatives.

Also, thanks for the PowerShell suggestions, but that's not possible now.

Comment: You got the ping method wrong. You would use a host that you *can* reach (localhost) and ping it 30 times, resulting in a 30sec wait. `ping -n 30 127.0.0.1`. It's still silly, using PS would be the more modern alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sleep in a batch file?](http://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: @Xalorous: This answer doesn't address the "non-interactive" restriction, and pinging `192.0.2.0/24` is still silly.

Comment: It does answer it.

Comment: @Xalorous:  happy to remove a dupe, but I agree w/ Sven . . . they answer you cite doesn't cover options for non-interactive sessions.  If you can quote from there, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Sven:  PowerShell is not an option at this point.   Thanks for the `-n 30` improvement.  At least then the silly hack is portable to all deployments.  I gather there's nothing "not silly" available for this?

Comment: The timeout would get interrupted if the user hits any key; however, the command also accepts the optional switch /nobreak, which effectively ignores anything the user may press, except an explicit CTRL-C:
`timeout /t 30 /nobreak`


Additionally, if you don't want the command to print its countdown on the screen, you can redirect its output to NUL:
`timeout /t 30 /nobreak > NUL`

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php  There's a number of options here.  Find or write a utility for the sleep function.  A compiled program or a vbs or kixtart script may be your best options in this case.

Comment: @Xalorous I would accept that last answer as the best.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php

> ## Non-DOS Scripting
>
> Use the SysSleep function whenever you need a time delay in Rexx scripts.
>   SysSleep is available in OS/2's (native) RexxUtil module and in Patrick McPhee's RegUtil module for 32-bits Windows.
>
> Use the Sleep command for time delays in KiXtart scripts.
>
> Use WScript.Sleep, followed by the delay in milliseconds in VBScript and JScript (unfortunately, this method is not available in HTAs).
>
> The following batch code uses a temporary VBScript file to generate an accurate delay:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM %1 is the number of seconds for the delay, as specified on the command line
> "%Temp%.\sleep.vbs" ECHO WScript.Sleep %~1 * 1000
>> CSCRIPT //NoLogo "%Temp%.\sleep.vbs"
>> DEL "%Temp%.\sleep.vbs"
```

*Not my solution, I just found it:*